# Bootstrap footer on bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have the footer of my site to stay always on the bottom. As well as I would like to have the content area to have at least the height of the viewport. Meaning in the viewport you should see the `header` on op. The `content` part in the middle and the `footer` on the bottom. If the article is longer than fits in the viewport the footer should go down and the content part should be longer.

Here is my code http://bit.ly/1Bl3Jd5

Thanks very much.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap `.container` and `.footer` with another container and apply styles:

```
#fullheight {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 146px;
}
```

For the footer you need to add:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vmjc1w2q/

Reduce preview height to see the effect.

**edit**

If you want other behaviour try this:

```
footer {
    width:100%;
    height:143px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To force the footer to be always visible, set its position to absolute.

CSS:

```
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:143px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Now I get what you want. http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ shows how you can archive the behavior:

CSS:

```
html, body { height:100%; }

#main { padding-bottom: 143px; }

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height:100%;
}

#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:143px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work on all page. Take for example this page:http://bit.ly/ZdNOQi there the content flows behind the footer and continues below it.

Comment: Gotcha, I edited the post.

Comment: Is this also the way it should be done with  Bootstrap?